# When calling an exported class of a C++ DLL by C#, C-style string members of the class are OK in one exported function, but not in the other

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllimport, dllexport

C++ console calls DLL OK, but not C#.

In the exported function `setInputs` , the `const char*`-type public member of class object is set OK, but in the exported function `run`, it becomes some meaningless characters.

exported DLL:

```
namespace{
    CLASS*CLASS_Ptr_Object=new CLASS();
    }

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void setInputs(char*char_Ptr_Model,int int_Type){
        CLASS_Ptr_Object->m_char_Ptr_Input_Model=char_Ptr_Model;//when I print the public member m_char_Ptr_Input_Model, I see it is OK here
        CLASS_Ptr_Object->m_int_Type=int_Type;//int and double types are always OK
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void run(){
    CLASS_Ptr_Object->run();//when I print the public member m_char_Ptr_Input_Model, I observe it has become some meaningless characters, although it was OK in previous exported function
}
```

how the public member is defined in header file:

```
class CLASS
    {

    //...

    public:
        const char*m_char_Ptr_Input_Model;
    };
```

Invoke in C#:

```
[DllImport(@"DLL.dll", EntryPoint = "setInputs")]
        public static extern setInputs(
            [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string char_Ptr_Model
            , [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]int int_Type
             );

 [DllImport(@"DLL.dll", EntryPoint = "run")]
 public static extern run();
```

Comment: `CLASS_Ptr_Object->m_char_Ptr_Input_Model=char_Ptr_Model;` Normally, you want to *copy* the string data to a buffer, not assign a pointer.

Comment: `Assign a pointer works fine`  You cannot rely on this.  First, what does `run` do exactly?  Also, where do you call `setInputs`?  The convention, at least for your implementation, is for the DLL exported function to copy the string data to a buffer allocated by the DLL.  You don't store the pointer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `run` reads a file whose name is determined by `m_char_Ptr_Input_Model`. I call `setInputs` before `run`.

Comment: I'm going to bet that if you changed your class member to be a char array and not a `char *`, and copied the data to that array your problems will go away.  If you want an example, look how a typical Windows API function implements the handling of strings.  The functions work on the *buffer* pointed to by the pointer -- the pointer itself is not stored for later use by the DLL function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Even if the pointer is a class member, it is not stored for later use? Anyway, I think I should try buffer.

Comment: It isn't the pointer, it is the `value` that the pointer is being set to.  The problem that you have is that you have no control of what that pointer will point to after that function is called.  Maybe C# garbage collection kicked in and you are no longer pointing to valid data.  That's why you save the data to a buffer, ensuring the data is intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of the character buffer that supplied by the C# marshaller is only valid for the duration of the call to `setInputs`. As soon as `setInputs` finishes, referring to that buffer is invalid.

The marshaller creates a temporary buffer to hold the character array, converts from the UTF-16 .net string to an 8 bit string. And then calls `setInputs` passing the address of the temporary buffer. When `setInputs` returns, the temporary buffer is destroyed. But you've held on to the address of that buffer and now you have a pointer to who knows what.

You will need to take a copy of the string. The simplest way is to declare the member to be of type `std::string` and use the assignment operator that accepts a `const char*` assignment source.

Comment: It worked: I defined the member with `std::string` and did some conversions between `const char*` and `std::string`.

Comment: Just as my comment suggested -- assigning to a `std::string` copies the data, the pointer is *not* stored.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your exported DLL function that handles strings is that you're relying that the calling language (in your case C#) handles pointers in the same manner as C++.  As the answer that David Heffeman has given, you can't assume that the calling language uses the same semantics as a C++ program would use.

If the calling program were C++, and if the pointer points to the string after the DLL call, then of course you will see that the DLL pointer also points to the string.  But strings in other languages, and marshaling of such strings to DLL functions can and will work differently than the "simple" C++ model.

Assuming we're not talking about COM, but just generic string handling for non-COM DLL's, if you look at how a typical Windows API function handles strings, it uses one of the following methods:

**For accepting strings:**

An `LPCTSTR` is usually the parameter type, and the Windows API function takes the pointer provided and copies the contents of the buffer to an internal buffer (if that's the purpose of the function).  This could mean storing the value in a char array, or as the answer suggested, stored in a `std::string` or some other container internal to the DLL.  Thus, when the function returns, the pointer value that was originally passed is no longer referred to -- the data is intact within the DLL.

**For returning strings:**

An `LPTSTR` is passed as a parameter, along with a length argument denoting the maximum number of characters to copy from the Windows API function to the buffer.  Another variant is that the API function documents how big the buffer should be, and the caller has to ensure that the buffer is big enough.  The DLL function then copies the data to the buffer and returns.

In none of the above scenarios does the DLL store the pointer to the buffer.

Comment: Probably the majority of Win32 functions don't take copies because they don't need to hold on the the string after the function returns.